# Expression Language API in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, el

I'm having problems with EL in Jboss (doesn't work with enum class). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955717/compare-enum-el-jboss) is related with my problem. This are all tests I did with Jboss EAP 7.0 and Java 1.8 over Ubuntu 14.04 with a VM:

1 - Include in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Result: **FAIL**

2 - Include in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.M15</version>
<dependency>
```

Result: **FAIL**

3 - Include in my project (WEB-INF/lib) `el-api.jar` directly copied from Tomcat 8.0.24

Result: **FAIL**

4 - Remove from Jboss the module `javax.el.api.main`, that include `jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.6.Final-redhat-1.jar`

Result: **FAIL** (Jboss fail to start)

I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @BalusC, please, don't mark as duplicate, related post don't solve my problem.

Comment: You are right, it is for this that I have updated the server to Jboss 7.0, released 2016-05-10 as you can see here: https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/

And as I mentioned in my post, this version include the library EL 3.0 (`jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.6.Final-redhat-1.jar`). The file META-INF indicates: **Implementation-Title: Expression Language 3.0 API**

And tomcat 8 was released some years ago: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Releases

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The problem here is related to this bug in EAP 7 (and WildFly 10) - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-5613. The enums in EL should work in WildFly 10.1 (and EAP 7.1 once ready). Don't use any EL-related imports in your pom.xml (and if you really want it, then scope it as "provided").

Comment: Thanks for your comment @kwart, I only did add the dependencies to test, now I don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

*Making an answer from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010813/expression-language-api-in-jboss#comment-71217202).*

The problem is related to bugs [JBEAP-5613](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-5613) in EAP 7.0 and [WFLY-6939](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6939) in WildFly 10.0.

The enums in EL already work in WildFly 10.1 and they will work in EAP 7.1 once ready.

Don't use any EL-related imports in your `pom.xml` (and if you really want it, then scope it as "provided").